# Difference between various numpy random functions

Tags: python, numpy

The [numpy.random](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) module defines the following 4 functions that all seem to return a float betweeb [0, 1.0) from the continuous uniform distribution. What (if any) is the difference between these functions?

> random_sample([size])     Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).
>
> random([size])    Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).
>
> ranf([size])  Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).
>
> sample([size])    Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).

--------------------------- Edit Follows ---------------------------------------

I found the following in `numpy.random` source code that supports @askewchan's answer:

```
# Some aliases:
ranf = random = sample = random_sample
__all__.extend(['ranf','random','sample'])
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Nothing.

They're just aliases to `random_sample`:

```
In [660]: np.random.random
Out[660]: <function random_sample>

In [661]: np.random.ranf
Out[661]: <function random_sample>

In [662]: np.random.sample
Out[662]: <function random_sample>

In [663]: np.random.random_sample is np.random.random
Out[663]: True

In [664]: np.random.random_sample is np.random.ranf
Out[664]: True

In [665]: np.random.random_sample is np.random.sample
Out[665]: True
```

Comment: Thanks, added source-code to my question that confirms your answer

Comment: This is hilarious. What's the reasoning?

Comment: @Zapurdead, I would imagine that `random` and `sample` were basically alternative names that someone decided to keep. `ranf` may be a standard name from some other source or community.

Comment: What's the difference between these and `np.random.rand`? (`np.random.random is np.random.rand == False`)

Comment: @Will, one practical difference is the call signature: for array shape `s = (2, 3)`, call `random(s)` or `rand(*s)`. Without further research, I imagine that's the main difference; the help string for `rand` says: *This is a convenience function. If you want an interface that takes a shape-tuple as the first argument, refer to `np.random.random_sample`.*

Answer (score 0):

I got different answers.

```
print(np.random.random)
print(np.random.ranf)
print(np.random.sample)
print(np.random.rand)
print(np.random.random_sample is np.random.random)
print(np.random.random_sample is np.random.ranf)
print(np.random.random_sample is np.random.sample)


<built-in method random of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x000001FC2C459D08>
<built-in function ranf>
<built-in function sample>
<built-in method rand of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x000001FC2C459D08>
False
False
False
```

Comment: I didn't get the answer as you got. Here's mine, on Python 3.7.3, windows 10, with np.version.full_version == '1.16.4'

`<built-in method random_sample of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x00000124C7E59F30>
<built-in method random_sample of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x00000124C7E59F30>
<built-in method random_sample of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x00000124C7E59F30>
<built-in method rand of mtrand.RandomState object at 0x00000124C7E59F30>
True
True
True`