# np.random.rand vs np.random.random

Tags: python, numpy

I find Python (and its ecosystem) to be full of strange conventions and inconsistencies and this is another example:

np.random.rand

> Create an array of the given shape and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

np.random.random

> Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0). Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval.

??? What exactly is the difference there?

Comment: There is a difference between a "continuous uniform" distribution and a uniform distribution. This could help clarify it for you:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24542083/6328256

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution

Comment: This is probably the same case here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634281/2285236

Comment: @ayhan that is correct!

Comment: @shash678 that has nothing to do with what I'm asking about. Those two functions are for generating a standard norm or a specific norm (choose mean and variance/sd).

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary I literally quoted from that page.. and no, there isn't a difference unless they had said "discrete" and "continuous", and discrete doesn't make sense between 0 and 1. Check the answer, the two functions are actually the same, seems like just a convention for matlab users and to confuse/annoy others

Comment: @Spacemonkey I thought it possible you overlooked it. I really wanted to believe they were going for discrete and continuous uniform distributions because two identical but differently named functions is asinine but hey, egg on my face. Glad you got an answer!

Comment: @Caleb_McCreary I have forgiven your sins

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First note that `numpy.random.random` is actually an alias for [`numpy.random.random_sample`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.random_sample.html).  I'll use the latter in the following.  (See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829185/difference-between-various-numpy-random-functions) for more aliases.)

Both functions generate samples from the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) on [0, 1).  The only difference is in how the arguments are handled.  With [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html), the length of each dimension of the output array is a separate argument.  With `numpy.random.random_sample`, the shape argument is a single tuple.

For example, to create an array of samples with shape (3, 5), you can write

```
sample = np.random.rand(3, 5)
```

or

```
sample = np.random.random_sample((3, 5))
```

(Really, that's it.)

---

*Update*

As of version 1.17, NumPy has a new [random API](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html).  The recommended method for generating samples from the uniform distribution on [0, 1) is:

```
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()  # Create a default Generator.
>>> rng.random(size=10)  # Generate 10 samples.
array([0.00416913, 0.31533329, 0.19057857, 0.48732511, 0.40638395,
       0.32165646, 0.02597142, 0.19788567, 0.08142055, 0.15755424])
```

The new [`Generator`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generator.html) class does not have the `rand()` or `random_sample()` methods.  There *is* a `uniform()` method that allows you to specify the lower and upper bounds of the distribution.  E.g.

```
>>> rng.uniform(1, 2, size=10)
array([1.75573298, 1.79862591, 1.53700962, 1.29183769, 1.16439681,
       1.64413869, 1.7675135 , 1.02121057, 1.37345967, 1.73589452])
```

The old functions in the `numpy.random` namespace will continue to work, but they are considered "frozen", with no ongoing development.  If you are writing new code, and you don't have to support pre-1.17 versions of numpy, it is recommended that you use the new random API.

Comment: right, so there is actually no difference. I wonder why we have two functions with different names that do the same thing.. IMHO they should clean this up.

Comment: There are historical reasons for these, probably related to making the transition to Python+Numpy easier for Matlab programmers (c.f. [Matlab's `rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)).   Cleaning it up might cause more trouble than it is worth, because there is likely a lot of existing code that uses the different versions of the functions.

Comment: It does seem like Python's community values "quick hacks cuz it's easy for me" over consistency. The best example of this is the matplotlib's convention to use numbers like "112" to mean (1,1,2) when creating subplots.. anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Practically speaking, @WarrenWeckesser is probably right about not cleaning it up.  That said, I felt *exactly* like SpaceMonkey when trying to remember the difference in parameter arguments to `np.zeros((tuple dimensions arg))` vs. `np.random.randn(dim1, dim2, dim3)`

Comment: Cleaning up API which is published is NO WAY. You ever heard of OPEN/CLOSE principle in SOLID ??? You can only add new API . Which has a confusion potential like the comments prove. Which seems to increase the problem. As you see yourself: Programming community lacks a good solution to this! Indeed the NumPy API seems totally overloaded. But you see- it is not easy. E.g. I have seen "zeros()" code with dimensions being not a tuple. API ist a very weak pattern, but we lack a better. Intelligent API which poses you questions- anything would work better...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question. This shows the outputs are identical. The difference is in input format (single arg for dimensions (tuple or list) vs a sequence of dimension args):

```
# np.random.random([2,3]) vs np.random.rand(2,3)

print()
np.random.seed(1)
print('  .. np.random.random([2,3]):\n', np.random.random([2,3]))
print()
np.random.seed(1)
print('  .. np.random.rand(2,3):\n', np.random.rand(2,3))

# output

 .. np.random.random([2,3]):
 [[4.17022005e-01 7.20324493e-01 1.14374817e-04]
 [3.02332573e-01 1.46755891e-01 9.23385948e-02]]

  .. np.random.rand(2,3):
 [[4.17022005e-01 7.20324493e-01 1.14374817e-04]
 [3.02332573e-01 1.46755891e-01 9.23385948e-02]]
```